# Cordova/Phonegap - Building DataTables with WebSQL

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, web-sql

I'm making a small application on Android/iOS in Cordova(Phonegap). The main function of the app is to maintain some local data in a database.

For this reason I've used the WebSQL, cordova has a API to use it etc.. 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

But now i want to make a CRUD table. (Create, Read, Update, Delete) 
Because i'm using Cordova i cant use PHP. The only things cordova supports are Javascript CSS and HTML. (thats why the WEBSQL). I'm not gonna use a webservice to connect with an online database (app must be used offline as well, and syncing <- its a small app, don't want to make things complicated)

**So my question here is:** Is there a library or framework etc.. that will make "DataTables" very fast that only works with javascript/websql? I'm not gonna program it all manually if there is a solution for this.

I have checked this: 
https://editor.datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html
Its perfect in all matters ! except it uses PHP...

So is there anything out there that can help me fix this fast? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use CRUD with WebSQL. Whats the problem with using CRUD with WebSQL? WebSQL for Cordova/phonegap use SQLite internally. So your CRUD will work using WebSQL.

Comment: The question isn't if i can use CRUD in WebSQL. The question is if there is a library or framework that will simplify the making of this CRUD process. have a look at this https://editor.datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

Comment: As @Joe Aspara mentions, and you have already seen datatables, the example you saw uses PHP but you can provide any data source of your choice. See https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array

Answer (score 0):

I used jQuery DataTables (http://www.datatables.net) for this purpose and I can recommend you to use it too.